# How strong is Sun magnetic field on Moon surface? And on Mars?

Tags: the-sun, magnetic-field, electromagnetism

I wan to calculate the voltage difference generated by sun EM Field on a wire placed on Moon or Mars surface, but I can't find consistent data about solar EM Field.
I found different values:

> The magnetic field at an average place on the Sun is around 1 Gauss,
>   about twice as strong as the average field on the surface of Earth
>   (around **0.5 Gauss**).

https://www.windows2universe.org/sun/sun_magnetic_field.html

> The Sun’s magnetic field During solar minimum, the magnetic field of
>   the Sun looks similar to Earth’s magnetic field. It looks a bit like
>   an ordinary bar magnet with closed lines close to the equator and open
>   field lines near the poles. Scientist call those areas a dipole. **The
>   dipole field of the Sun is about as strong as a magnet on a
>   refrigerator (around 50 gauss)**. The magnetic field of the Earth is
>   about 100 times weaker.

https://www.spaceweatherlive.com/en/help/the-interplanetary-magnetic-field-imf

> Magnetic field at Earth orbit
>
> A video simulation of Earth's magnetic field interacting with the
>   (solar) interplanetary magnetic field (IMF) The plasma in the
>   interplanetary medium is also responsible for the strength of the
>   Sun's magnetic field at the orbit of the Earth being over 100 times
>   greater than originally anticipated. If space were a vacuum, then the
>   Sun's magnetic dipole field, about 10^−4 teslas at the surface of the
>   Sun, would reduce with the inverse cube of the distance to about 10−11
>   teslas. But satellite observations show that it is about 100 times
>   greater at around **10^−9 teslas**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_magnetic_field

Edit: new source says IMF strength at Earth distance is around [6 nT](https://books.google.it/books?id=h2-NjUg4RtEC&pg=PA317&lpg=PA317&dq=imf%20intensity%20on%20the%20moon&source=bl&ots=n81Fp9Nxjo&sig=ACfU3U27KA_s41CMUkxbZyQUVZx-CgLnNA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY38f5x7jnAhWDyKYKHYqhCzUQ6AEwB3oECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=about%206%20nT&f=false)

Does it exist a quantitative equivalent of this tipical picture, which is just qualitative?
[image]

Comment: EMF usually stands for electromotive force in the context of electromagnetism. Best to avoid it in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is:

- Moon: **~6 nanoTesla**
- Mars: **>1 nanoTesla**

[Tesla] = $\frac{[V][s]}{[m^2]}$ = $\frac{[N]}{[A][m]}$

1 nT = $10^{-9}$ T

---

This plot from Explorer 35 spacecraft, which orbited Moon in 1967, explains answer:
[image: Interplanetary Magnetic Field around the Moon]

- Title: The magnetic fields of Mercury, Mars, and moon
- Authors: Ness,   N. F.
- Journal: In: Annual review of earth and planetary sciences.   Volume 7. (A79-37176 15-42) Palo Alto, Calif., Annual Reviews, Inc.,   1979, p. 249-288. Bibliographic Code: 1979AREPS...7..249N

Value of "sun magnetic field", actually named "Interplanetary Magnetic Field - IMF", is around **6 nanoTesla**, with its angles continuously changing (Theta =  0°/-40°, Phi = -30°/0°)

Paper also states that **there is only slight modification on IMF performed by the Moon**.

Subsequent studies revealed the presence of several "magnetic anomalies" in various regions of the Moon, where values of ~100 nT of local EMF were measured.

Further plots:

[MEASUREMENTS OF THE PERTURBED-INTERPLANETARY MAGNETIC FIELD IN THE LUNAR WAKE](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19680016292.pdf)
bY
Harold E. Taylor", K. W. Behannon and N. F. Ness

---

This plot shows instead the measured and modeled strength of IMF along the whole Solar System, based on Voyager data:
[image: IMF plot along solar system]
https://solarscience.msfc.nasa.gov/people/suess/Interstellar_Probe/IMF/IMF.html

HP (Helio Pause), BS (Bow Shock) and TS (Termination Shock) are depicted below:
[image: BS, TS and HP]

This image shows instead planets distances from sun (beware: logarithmic scale!):
[image: Planets distances]

Average distance of **Mars** from Sun is 1.5 AU, which means that **IMF** is **> 1nT**.

Juno spacecraft measurements:

[image: Juno IMF measurements]

The interplanetary magnetic field observed by Juno enroute to Jupiter - Jacob R. Gruesbeck

---

Further data:

It appears that Open Circuit Voltage (Voc) on a wire moving into an EM field is given by ([source 1](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-522-space-propulsion-spring-2015/lecture-notes/MIT16_522S15_Lecture25.pdf), [source 2](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?2001ESASP.476...61I&defaultprint=YES&filetype=.pdf)):

- Voc = v * B * L

Hence current:

- I = v * B * L / Rw
- v = speed [m/s]
- B = EM field [Tesla] = $\frac{[V][s]}{[m^2]}$
- L = wire length [m]
- Rw = wire resistance [ohm]

and

- Rw = $\rho * L / A$
- $\rho$ = resistivity (copper = 1.68E-8 Ohm*m)
- L = length
- A = section area

Hence:

$I = \frac{v B L}{\rho  L / A}$

$I = \frac{v B A}{\rho}$

Earth+Moon speed around sun: ~30000 m/s  (3E+04)

Mars speed around sun: ~24000 m/s (2.4E+04)

It has also to be taken into account the rotation speed of IMF, given by Sun rotation period of [25.38 days](https://www.ann-geophys.net/37/299/2019/angeo-37-299-2019.pdf) (= 2pi radians in 2192832 seconds):

$\omega = 2.865 × 10^{−6} \frac{rad}{s}$

Hence linear speed:

v = ω * R

- Earth+Moon: R = 1 AU = 1.5E+11 m
- Mars: R = 1.5 AU = 1.5 * 1.5E+11 m = 2,25E+11 m

$V_{earth} = 2.865 * 10^{-6} * 1.5*10^{11} = 4.3 * 10^{5} [m/s]$

$V_{mars} = 2.865 * 10^{-6} * 1.5*1.5*10^{11} = 6.45 * 10^{5} [m/s]$

---

Control data

For Italian Tethered Satellite System ([TSS-1R](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/shuttle/shuttlemissions/archives/sts-75.html) on STS-75 Shuttle mision) 
 there are these known data:

- Satellite orbit height: 300 km
- Relative speed between orbiter and plasma: [7300 m/s](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/cbde/a02ed995bd4b1ed0ea1dfa38dc9eb43680c5.pdf?_ga=2.21371384.251691955.1581066436-1136504139.1581066436)
- Earth magnetic field: [20000-60000 nT](https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/84000/84266/magneticfield_swa_201406.jpg)
- Tether Length = ~20000 m
- Tether electric resistance: [2000](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/cbde/a02ed995bd4b1ed0ea1dfa38dc9eb43680c5.pdf?_ga=2.21371384.251691955.1581066436-1136504139.1581066436) or [260](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Luciano_Iess/publication/221964610_Space_tethers_an_overview/links/0fcfd511547300d864000000/Space-tethers-an-overview.pdf?origin=publication_detail) Ohm (?)
- Tether diameter: 2.54 mm
- Resulting DeltaV = [5000](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Luciano_Iess/publication/221964610_Space_tethers_an_overview/links/0fcfd511547300d864000000/Space-tethers-an-overview.pdf?origin=publication_detail) V or [3500](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19970011947.pdf) V
- Theoretical current achievable: [19A](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Luciano_Iess/publication/221964610_Space_tethers_an_overview/links/0fcfd511547300d864000000/Space-tethers-an-overview.pdf?origin=publication_detail)
- Actual current achieved: [1](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19970011947.pdf) A