# Could a Mars rover reliably navigate using the local magnetic fields?

Tags: mars, rovers, navigation, magnetic-field

> Mars does not have a global magnetic field which guides charged particles entering the atmosphere. Mars has multiple umbrella-shaped magnetic fields mainly in the Southern Hemisphere, which are remnants of a global field that decayed billions of years ago.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars)

[This article](https://www.planetary.org/articles/1710) states that the maximum local magnetic field on Mars is 1500 nanotesla.  [This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/45057/26446) states that older crust typically has a magnetic field of 15-20 nanotesla, with younger crust less than 15 nanotesla.  [Another answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41263/26446) claims ">1" nanotesla.

Suppose we landed a rover in a region with a 15-20 nT magnetic field.  **Would a rover be able to reliably navigate** (i.e. know which way is "north") **using these local magnetic fields?**  Or is there some issue that would make such navigation unreliable?

(We can assume that the rover won't travel far enough to leave the local magnetic field.)

[image: Mars magnetic field]

Comment: There will be competing sources of weak magnetic fields that may be variable: https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/goddard/2020/mars-electric-currents and paywalled: [The global current systems of the Martian induced magnetosphere](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41550-020-1099-y)

Comment: and some [eye candy](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/12397)